# Passing callback parameters to setTimeout() does not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I used the code in js setTimeout function it is working in firefox ;i,e it is reloaded with in seconds. but not working in IE.
I changed the method as 'POST', but not request not supported then it changed again in to 'GET'.
Any solution ?

```
function getCallDetails(cId){
    $.ajax( {
        url : 'callInfo.html?cId='+cId,
        method : "GET",
         dataType: "json",     
        success : function(data) {
        callResult=data.rows;

        showCallDetails(callResult,cId);
        },
        failure : function(form, action) {
        }
    });
    window.setTimeout(getCallDetails, 1000,[cId]);

}
```

Comment: For future reference, please include the version of IE tried (update the post as required). Also, take a peak at the XHR *request and response* in situations like this. (I am not sure what IE offers, but there is always fiddler2.) It would show strange data.

Comment: I used both 8 and 9 version of IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    getCallDetails(cId);
}, 1000);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

You're using a non-IE-compatible version of `setTimeout`.
In IE, there is no way to pass parameters to the callback.

Also, calling `setTimeout` there is very wrong; you will get exponentially more concurrent requests because each call generates two more calls.

Comment: All browsers support sending arguments into setTimeout except IE. IE instead allows sending a language argument instead (vbscript, jscript or JavaScript).

Comment: +1 just for pointing out the "fork bomb" behavior. It does miss the "how to solve this problem" bit, though.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following instead:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { getCallDetails(cId); }, 1000);
```

Also I would move that line into the success callback.

Comment: But why move it to the success callback? (And what happens on failure?)

Comment: @pst: That's the OP's concern.

Answer (score 2):

this is due to cache problem in IE

this is solved by

```
 function getCallDetails(cId){
        $.ajax( {
            url : 'callInfo.html?cId='+cId+'&randomNo='+ Math.rand(),
            method : "GET",
             dataType: "json",     
            success : function(data) {
            callResult=data.rows;

            showCallDetails(callResult,cId);
            },
            failure : function(form, action) {
            }
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() { getCallDetails(cId); }, 1000);


    }
```

and random no ignored @ server side.

Comment: this is also useful:    $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});