# How to add arguments to .on('ready') function in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to add popups to omnivore layers in Leaflet. I'm going to have a lot of these layers, so I want to write a function to add the same style and popup to each layer. Each of the layers needs to have its own popup text. I wrote the function, but when I try to run the code, I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

This code won't work:

```
function stylize(place) {
  this.setStyle({
    color: '#f00',
    opacity: 1
  });
  this.bindPopup(place);
  this.addTo(mapLayer);
};

omnivore.gpx('place-a.gpx')
.on('ready', stylize('Place A'));
```

And this won't work:

```
omnivore.gpx('place-a.gpx')
.on('ready', function() {stylize('Place A');});
```

While this will:

```
function stylize() {
  this.setStyle({
    color: '#f00',
    opacity: 1
  });
  this.bindPopup('Place A');
  this.addTo(mapLayer);
};

omnivore.gpx('place-a.gpx')
.on('ready', stylize);
```

Why am I not able to add arguments to this function?

Comment: Whenever you have something of the form `foo(bar())`, `bar` is executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. So in your case, instead of passing a reference to `stylize` to `.on()`, you are executing `stylize` and pass its return value to `.on()` (which is not a function).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already tried .on('ready', function() {stylize('Place A');}); which seems to be what your duplicate question suggests. That isn't working either.

Comment: True, reopened and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to pass arguments to callbacks in general is covered in [Javascript: how to pass parameters to callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456875/javascript-how-to-pass-parameters-to-callback-function) .

However, you also relying on `this` referring to a specific object. So you have to set `this` explicitly, using [**`.call`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
omnivore.gpx('place-a.gpx').on('ready', function() {
  stylize.call(this, 'Place A');
});
```

To learn more about `this`, have a look at the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).